# how to catch response and display the exception handle in back-end in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, exception, display, sweetalert

i am trying to catch the response and display in the browser when data is not found but i didn't got idea how to do it when response is in array.

In the postman response is in following way:
[
{
"responseStatus": "No record found!!",
"responseCode": "0"
}
]
i tried to catch and display in the browser but not worked. i tried this way:

```
 if (response.responseCode == "0") {
        Swal.fire({
          icon:"warning",
          title: 'Data Not Exists!',
          confirmButtonColor: 'green',
        })
      }
```

How to catch response and display in browser when response given is in array form like :[
{
"responseStatus": "No record found!!",
"responseCode": "0"
}
]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `if (response.responseCode == "0") {`

What does the `response` look like?

Is it this?

```
response = [ 
  { "responseStatus": "No record found!!", "responseCode": "0" } 
];
```

or this?

```
response = { "responseStatus": "No record found!!", "responseCode": "0" };
```

The first one is an array, so you will need to do `response[0].responseCode`. The `[0]` is to reach into the array and get the first element.

You will of course need to add some logics to handle when the response returns the success object/array.

Comment: Thank you very much sir,  your answer "response[0].responseCode" worked perfectly.

Comment: You are welcome. Please give a green check to this answer to help future developers find this solution faster.